# How to Install Chrome on a Distroless Image

Tags: spring-boot, docker, selenium-chromedriver, dockerfile

My Java Spring Boot project requires chrome headless to be installed.

The Java base image that I am currently using is
`gcr.io/distroless/java-debian10`.

How do I go about installing Chrome on top of this image?